# Bootstrap media object cannot align properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [Bootstrap 3 media objects](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media)  and I have this code here dynamically I want to have 4 columns in one row,but the problem is that the last row will have spaces inbetween to the second row.
here is my code.

//content.php

```
for(var i=0;i<12;i++){
                mymdedia+=
                    '<div class="media col-sm-3">'+
                      '<div class="media-left">'+
                         '<a href="#">'+
                            '<img src=".....">'+
                          '</a>'+
                      '</div>'+
                         '<div class="media-body">'+
                             '<h4 class="media-heading">'John Doe'</h4>'+
                             '<p>Live: '+data[i].address+'</p>'+

                          '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
        }
    $('#mycontainer').append(mymdedia);
```

//index.php

```
 <div class="someclass">
                  <div class="row" id="mycontainer">

                  </div>
            </div>
```

and this is the result looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are placing all the media objects in one row ... and they don't fit.

In every row that you've opened ( `<div class='row'>...</div>` ) you can place only 4 `<div class='media col-sm-3'></div>` ... because each col size = 3 ... ( 4x3 = 12 )

So in the `for` loop, after each 4 media objects - you should close the current row div and create a new `<div class='row'>` ...

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BJa3qdbKcYMDwhW809gp?p=preview

Right after the for loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<12;i++){
    if ( i && i % 4 == 0 )
      mymdedia += '</div><div class="row">';    // close row and create a new one

     ... your original code ...

}

mymdedia += '</div>' // close the last row outside the for loop ...
```